# CanCan best practice : automatically grant db-based permissions on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, database-permissions

I use CanCan and a `Permission` model to manage permissions on a `Folder` model.

**When a user creates a folder, i want to create a permission to write for this user** on the folder (i.e. create a permission record with field `action` set to 'write', belonging to both a user and a folder), knowing that this permission might be modified later by an admin (users are not owners of the folders they created). Oddly enough, if a user is admin no permission should be created.

I could use a callback on `Folder` to do the job, but i don't think that making `current_user` available to the models directly is a good idea.

So here are the options I consider :

1. make the dirty job in the controller. I don't like it that much, it's not DRY
2. craft a `save_and_grant_permission( user, action )` method on `Folder` that would do the job, wrapping the process in a transaction. Problem is i'd have to remember to always use this and not only `save`

**So I'd like to know :**

- if there are other alternatives
- what would be the best practice in this case

**update**

For now, i chose solution two and used `nested_attributes` :

```
def save_and_grant_permission( user, action )
  return save if user.admin?
  permission = permissions.where( user_id: user.id ).first
  self.permissions_attributes = [
    {id: permission.try(:id), user_id: user.id, action: action.to_s}
  ]
  save
end
```

If no better solution shows up here, i'll close the question and move it to StackExchange::CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should give your folder a reference to a user in the form of an author.

You can base your permissions on the author of the folder and for example define an after_create callback that creates a permission for the folder's author.

Comment: yeah, why not, it's simple and efficient. I was so deep down in the mud with this project I don't know why I did not thought of that. thanks